How to change default time in primevue calendar
By default, the current time is set at the moment, but it needs to be 00:00
for example, now the time 21:09 is set by default to 21:09, but I need it to be 00:00
<Calendar
  v-model="filter.started_at"
  dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"
  showIcon
  iconDisplay="input"
  placeholder="date"
  class="tournaments-filter__field"
  showButtonBar
  show-time
/>

what do I need to add for this?

Did you try to set that v-model to 00:00?

Initially vmodel is null, why does it need to be changed to 00:00?

So that you have the default time that you want?

This works well
<script setup>
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';
import { startOfDay } from "date-fns";

const time = ref()

function updateTime(e) {
  console.log(startOfDay(e))
  time.value = startOfDay(e)
}
</script>

<template>
  <Calendar @dateSelect="updateTime($event)" show-time hour-format="24" />
</template>

I am here using date-fns startOfDay to bring the whole Date object to midnight aka

Sun May 12 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

